# How to change a '.' to ' ' in a txt file?

Tags: c++

I am having trouble switching a period '.' to a space ' '. Here is my code :

```
void readTicToeBoard(char ticToe[][3])
{
   char getFileName[256];

   ifstream fin;

   //get the filename                                                                                                                                                                
   cout << "Enter source filename: ";
   cin >> getFileName;

   fin.open(getFileName);
   //error check                                                                                                                                                                     
   if (fin.fail())
   {
      cout << "Error reading file.";

   }

   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   {
      for (int t = 0; t < 3; t++)
      {
         if (t == '.')
         t = ' ';
         fin >> ticToe[t][i];
      }
   }
}
```

I have tried changing the t = ' '; to cout << ' '; as well and that does not seem to work. I Don't think I have a full understanding on how to change characters to something else.

Comment: in english, what are you trying to do? read in the board, converting all dots to spaces?

Comment: Note `t` is an `int` ranging from 0 to 2. However, you're comparing it to the character '.'.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It looks like you need to learn how arrays work in C or C++. Here's [a tutorial](http://www.learn-c.org/en/Arrays)

Comment: In english, I am trying to convert '.' to ' '. aka change a period to a space.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably change your inner loop to

```
  for (int t = 0; t < 3; t++)
  {
     fin >> ticToe[t][i];
     if (ticToe[t][i] == '.')
         ticToe[t][i] = ' ';
  }
```

to achieve what you want, if I understood your question correctly.

Beyond that, it's not clear enough what you are actually asking for.